# How do I attach a behavior to the DataGridCells in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I can add the behavior to a `DataGrid` easily (assuming 'i' is the namespace for Microsoft interactivity library):

```
<DataGrid>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <MyDataGridBehavior />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

Is there a way to attach a behavior to the `DataGridCells` in the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are figuring out how this could be made via XAML I'm afraid it's not possible, due to `DataGridCells` are generated dynamically. But you can attach a behavior programmatically if you are able to catch each `DataGridCell` whilst it's been created.

For instance, you can create your own `DataGridTemplateColumn` and override its `GenerateElement` method. First parameter accepted by this method is your desired `DataGridCell`. When this method is called you can attach your `Behavior` this way:

```
public class MyTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    protected override System.Windows.FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        //Create instance of your behavior
        MyDataGridBehavior b = new MyDataGridBehavior();

        //Attach behavior to the DataGridCell
        System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction.GetBehaviors(cell).Add(b);

        return base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this type of column in your DataGrid like other regular columns.

Another approach:

Create a style and apply it to `<DataGrid.CellStyle>` property in your XAML and then set the `Template` property to whatever you want. Now you can set the Behavior to the root of the Visual Tree of your template. For example:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid> <!-- root element -->
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <My:MyDataGridBehavior/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                        ... <!-- elements to show content -->

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
```